# SQL database on remote Golang instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, heroku, go

I'm trying to launch a Go app on Heroku. This app does use a fairly large SQL database; currently, the database is on my local and I call this

`db, err := sqlx.MustConnect("mysql", username+":"+password+"@tcp(localhost:3306)/"+environment)`

in my code. The data is accessible as a `.sql` file from an AWS bucket. Is there anyway I could have my app directly connect to this sql file, or host the database somewhere other than localhost?

Comment: Do you want to import that into your Heroku database?

Comment: Assuming that: you would either use a MySQL add-on from a provider that works with Heroku, or Amazon RDS (MySQL). The latter can definitely import from S3.

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

In heroku website, go to My Apps and select the app on which you have installed ClearDB.

On the top corner click on **Addons** and then select **ClearDB MySQL Database**.
Once there, click on your database and choose the '**Endpoint Information**' tab. There you see your username/password. The URL to the database can be acquired by running 
`heroku config --app <YOUR-APP-NAME>` in the command line.

In my case, it was something like: mysql://user:pass@**us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com**/TABLE?reconnect=true
What you need is this part: **us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com**

PS:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql